# How to handle multiple backend api call for single rest call through gateway

Tags: nginx, api-gateway, kong

- **Below are service which is running on the system:**

  1. **Rest client service:** client assesing the rest backend service.
  2. **Api gateway:** all rest client request will go through gateway.
  3. **Session manager service:** Service which is holding the global session in the system.
  4. **Authorization service:** Service which make the decision, whether current global can perform the operation.
  5. **Rest backend service:** this is a kind of backend resource service. which only authorized user can access it.
- **Call flow understanding**
  -> When rest client application access the the Rest backend service, it is intercepted by gateway. Now Gateway will make rest api call to session Manager service to get the current global session.
  -> then Gateway will send the request backend service url and current session to the authorization service. Authorization service will
  make the decision if curruent session has authorization to for the request url by the client.
  -> if gateway will get success response from authorization service, then gateway will forward the incoming request to the rest backend
  service.
- **Pls find below diagram for more understanding:**
  [image]
- **Question:**

  - Is it possible to handle those flow using api gateway. if so how?
  - which gateway will better fit here. Nginx or Kong or anything else.
  - If possible, can you provide some example or article link which handles such scenario.

Comment: You can handle this with a kong plugin

Comment: Thanks Orel. But it will be great if you can provide some ref link to implement it.

Comment: create a plugin see https://docs.konghq.com/gateway-oss/2.5.x/plugin-development/ then in the handler function use a `http.new()` to do our call 3 and 4.

Comment: I wouldn't put all this business / flow logic in your API gateway.

Comment: I'm looking specifically for an example using express-gateway. I have the gateway set up, but I'm not sure how to compose the api's